# How to save object of django model without giving all fields values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

model of contact

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="contacts",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    assistant = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    assistant_phone = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    skype_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    pin_code = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can some fields have `blank=True` means we don't need to give a value to that field during creating a new object

views.py for saving new objects of contact model.

```
def save_contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST.get("fname")
        last_name = request.POST.get("lname")
        contact_name = request.POST.get("contact_name")
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        phone = request.POST.get("phone")
        mobile = request.POST.get("mobile")
        assistant = request.POST.get("assistant")
        assistant_phone = request.POST.get("assistant_phone")
        department = request.POST.get("department")
        fax = request.POST.get("fax")
        date_of_birth = request.POST.get("date_of_birth")
        skype_id = request.POST.get("skype_id")
        twitter = request.POST.get("twitter_id")
        country = check(request.POST.get("country")
        state = request.POST.get("state")
        city = request.POST.get("city")
        street = request.POST.get("street")
        pin_code = request.POST.get("pin_code")
        description = request.POST.get("description")
        contact_obj = Contact(owner=request.user,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,account_name=contact_name,title=title,email=email,phone=phone,mobile=mobile,assistant=assistant,assistant_phone=assistant_phone,Department=department,fax=fax,date_of_birth=date_of_birth,skype_id=skype_id,twitter=twitter,country=country,state=state,city=city,street=street,pin_code=pin_code,description=description)
        try:
            Contact.save(self=contact_obj)
        except:
            messages.success(request,"Something went wrong! Try again")
            return redirect("crm_contacts")
        messages.success(request,"Your contact has been successfully saved")
        return redirect("crm_contacts")
    else:
        messages.success(request,"Something went wrong! Try again")
        return redirect("crm_contacts")
```

Now the problem is that I need to give all field values in the new contact object. let's suppose if the user does not give any value of the phone field then I'm able to store it in the database I got an error during save the object. is there any way that I will give only those fields to contact object that has a value which is given by user so contact object can be store in the database.

**Error** = `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Comment: when you use pin_code = request.POST.get("pin_code"), it will have an empty string instead of None, because user posted an empty value. And when you try to save your model you will have a error for all int fields. In your case you need manually check that if given value is an empty string then it should be None. But you better you `ModelForm` and it will do all checks for you

Comment: @AndreyMaslov thanks i check with if-else and give none to empty strings and works but it showing none in HTML when I see the new contact object in HTML format. I think the modelform will be best I will use it.

Comment: you can add your checks when you create your model object `Contact(..., pin_code = pin_code if pin_code else None, ...)` but `ModelForm` would be better decision

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the model forms in Django. That way it will be more cleaner and the validations are inbuilt
[django model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

with forms, you can create a form  object and save them later

```
new_author = f.save(commit=False)
new_author.property = value
new_author.save()
```